# C++ name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, class, methods

so I searched for some solutions but didn't found any. I want to define my methods in their cpp files, but even when I include their .h files, the compiler doesn't recognize any of my classes and their attributes. Here is a part of my code:

```
 #include "Table.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Table Table::Table()
{
    capacite_ = MAXCAP;
    id_ = -1;
    nbPlaces_ = 1;
    occupee_ = false;
    commande_ = MAXCAP;
}
Table Table::Table(int id, int nbPlaces)
{
    id_ = id;
    nbPlaces_ = nbPlaces;
}
int Table::getId()
{
    return id_;
}
```

hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 8):

Constructors don't have a return type:

```
struct Table {
  Table();
};

Table::Table() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your header file is like this

```
#define MAXCAP (100)
class Table {

public:
  Table();
  Table(int id, int nbPlaces);
  ~Table() {}

  int getId();

private:
  int nbPlaces_;
  int id_;
  bool occupee_;
  int commande_;
  int capacite_;
};
```

try following code in your cpp file, this should fix the problem

```
#include "Table.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Table::Table() {
  capacite_ = MAXCAP;
  id_ = -1;
  nbPlaces_ = 1;
  occupee_ = false;
  commande_ = MAXCAP;
}

Table::Table(int id, int nbPlaces) {
  id_ = id;
  nbPlaces_ = nbPlaces;
}

int Table::getId() { return id_; }

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: You should have explained the problem with the code. However it was already answered sufficiently. I am not sure a new answer will help much.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I already tried this. It is still not recognizing the class Table but I don't know why

Comment: Have you checked ifdef flags in your header file?

Comment: ***It is still not recognizing the class Table but I don't know why*** That should be a new question (since this one is answered correctly) with the fixed code from this answer. In the new question make sure you include your header and any errors you had.